# How can I set a UIView to be the only receiver of touches?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app has a slide out navigation setup where the presented views (left and center) are both `child view controllers` of a `main view controller.` Now I am trying to use a magnifying glass within a `UIView` presented within the view of the `child view controller`. However both the `child view controller` and the `main view controller` have gesture recognizers.

I was hoping that setting `exclusiveTouch` to true on the desired `UIView` would do the trick, but it doesn't at all. **How can I put my application in a state such that the `main view controller` and the `child view controller` both don't receive these touches (I'm thinking of an off/off button) when I want the contained `UIView` only to receive them?** I need something that can be contained within one method rather than upending my entire architecture. Thanks for any suggestions

p.s. I'm happy to provide code, but it would be a lot of code to show the implementation of the slide out controller, etc. Am happy to post whatever is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work... But you could try adding a `TapGestureRecognizer` with a handler that doesn't do anything to the `mainViewController.view` and `childViewController.view` when you enter the `exclusiveTouch` state, then be sure to remove it when you exit the `exclusiveTouch` state.

I believe that the topmost gesture recognizer on a `UIView` is the one that routes all gestures on that view, so this should keep the gesture from being picked up and handled by the other recognizers lower on the stack.

Try this and let me know how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did not use this, but it made me realize I should just turn off my gesture recognizers rather than trying to beat them or capture the touch first.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution was to disable all gesture recognizers and not change anything else. Then `UIView` did capture the touches.